# CakePHP: Mysql search multiple queries on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have a query that is open to any number of words. Can be `john`, `john doe`, `john company`, `john doe, company`, or even `doe company` or 'company doe'.

You probably guessed I want to find this guy now. So I have to be looking for 3 columns (let's say `first_name`, `last_name`, `company`) with a  query of which I don't know the exact structure.

How would I construct a query with `MATCH/AGAINST` without security holes?

There are two things I am not clear here: 1) What the logic would be to get the right results and 2) how not to leave security holes. Here is what I mean about security - the only way I find to do fulltext search in CakePHP is with:

```
 'conditions' =>  "MATCH(SearchIndex.data) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
```

But then everybody says this is open to injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
'conditions' =>  array(
    "MATCH(SearchIndex.data) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)" => $q
),
```